# Syntax Errors in Code [C] - Eight Queens Puzzle

Tags: c, arrays, n-queens

Sorry for the vague title, I wasn't really sure how to explain. I'm trying to solve the Eight Queens puzzle.

For those unfamiliar with the eight queens puzzle:

---

This program is supposed to find a possible way that 8 queens can
be placed on an 8x8 chessboard so that the queens cannot
capture one another -- that is, so that no column, row, or
diagonal is occupied by more than one queen.

---

The way I have it mapped out in my head is:

1) I'll set the whole array: `chess[8][8] = {2}`

2) Go to the beginning of the array, and as long as `chess[i][j] == 2`, it will be reassigned to `1`. Then as soon as that happens, I have another program block called `set_illegal`, which will go and set the diagonals, row, and column to 0. (For that reason I will have to have `chess[8][8]` be a global variable.)

3) After set_illegal is finished, the test program will jump back into the loop of `assign_q` and the process will start all over again.

4) After this it will print out the solution. Unfortunately I didn't code this find multiple solutions... so it will only display 1 solution (kind of nooby programming lol...)

Any input is much appreciated!!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    #define N 8

    int chess[N][N] = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}, row1, column1; 
//the reason for row1 and column1 is so that set_row, set_column, and set_diagonal 
//will have a spot to start. Also I could have assigned all the elements in the array to 2 using a loop, but I was feeling a little lazy...

    void assign_q(int **chess[N][N]**);

    int main()
    {
        int row, column;

        assign_q(chess);

        for (row = 0; row < N; row++) //prints the whole table
        {
            for (column = 0; column < N; column++)
                printf("%d ", chess[row][column]);

            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void set_illegal(void);

    void assign_q(int chess[N][N])
    {
        int row, column;

        for (column = 0; column < N; column++)
        {
            for (row = 0; row < N; row++)
            {
                if (chess[row][column] == 2) //if the element of the array is equal to 2, then it will set it to 1
                {
                    chess[row][column] = 1;
                    row1 = column;
                    column1 = column;
                    set_illegal(); //goes through the column, row, and diagonal to set them all illegal
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void set_column(void);
    void set_row(void);
    void set_diagonal(void);

    void set_illegal()
    {
        set_column();
        set_row();
        set_diagonal();
    }

    void set_column()
    {
        int row;

        for (row = 0; row < N; row++)
            chess[row][column1] = 0; //sets the column illegal
    }

    void set_row()
    {
        int column;

        for (column = 0; column < N; column++)
            chess[row1][column] = 0; //sets the row illegal
    }

    void set_diagonal()
    {
        int row, column;

        for (row = row1 + 1, column = column1 + 1; row < N && column < N; row++, column++)
            chess[row][column] = 0; //sets diagonals in the slope of -1 downwards illegal

        for (row = row1 - 1, column = column1 - 1; row >= 0 && column >= 0; row--, column--)
            chess[row][column] = 0; //sets diagonals in the slope of -1 upwards illegal

        for (row = row1 - 1, column = column1 + 1; row >= 0 && column < N; row--, column++)
            chess[row][column] = 0; //sets diagonals in the slope of +1 upwards illegal

        for (row = row1 + 1, column = column1 - 1; row < N && column >= 0; row++, column--)
            chess[row][column] = 0; //sets diagonals in the slope of +1 downwards illegal
    }
```

---

After the change in bold, the only error I get is that the program doesnt actually work ahahaha. Anyways I'll figure that one out. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: So, what is the actual error?

Comment: @MSalters just added them in, sorry about that

Comment: `int chess[N][N] = {2}` this only set to 2 the chess[0][0]. other are set to 0

Comment: @Ôrel whoops... thats an easy fix, let me do that quickly

Comment: `void assign_q(int chess);` --> `void assign_q(int chess[N][N]);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY after that fix, i only have 2 errors left, which are pretty much the same error. It's a very odd error though...

Comment: you chaged only prototype. Of course function definition also needs to be changed.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yeah sorry i forgot to change that on here, i changed it on my code though

Comment: So syntax error should not occur now.

Comment: You can't do bold text within code. You have `void assign_q(int **chess[N][N]**);`; all the asterisks appear as asterisks. If you want to mark a line of code, use a comment.

Comment: lol... i bolded it to show my changes... obviously i wouldnt do that

Answer (score 0):

`void assign_q(int chess)` - I think you want a board here, not a single field.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? should i have `void assign_q(int chess[][])`?

Comment: thats what I was having trouble with mainly, is the syntax on calling that array

Comment: @NicolasDiken: `void assign_q(int chess[N][N])` - technically the last N is redundant, but it's good documentation to state what you expect. The first N is mandatory to figure out how the data is organized.

Comment: Try `void assign_q(int chess[8][8])`. `void assign_q(int chess[8][])` will also work. The parameter needs the first `[8]` to define how many `int`s are in one column, so it knows how many `int`s to jump to get to the next column in the array.

Comment: @Znapi `void assign_q(int chess[8][])` should be `void assign_q(int chess[][8])`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY oops, you're right. My mistake. `int chess[][8]` makes more sense too.